# Is it possible to have a peer to peer communication using nothing but PHP

Tags: php, p2p

Is it possible to implement a p2p using just PHP? Without Flash or Java and obviously without installing some sort of agent/client on one's computer.

so even though it might not be "true" p2p, but it'd use server to establish connection of some sort, but rest of communication must be done using p2p

i apologize for little miscommunication, by "php" i meant not a php binary, but a php script that hosted on web server remote from both peers, so each peer have nothing but a browser.

Comment: You may want to explain a little more what you mean by this question. How do you want to use php? With a webserver, or stand-alone? What should the user interface be able to do?

Comment: Yes, some clarification would be good.  I'm afraid I got downvoted for answering the question OP asked instead of the question they *meant* (which was "Can I implement a browser-based P2P service using only PHP", to which the answer is of course "no").

Comment: Why not just use Opera Unite file sharing? http://unite.opera.com/service/132/

Comment: The original question said - "Is it possible to implement a p2p using just PHP? Without Flash or Java and obviously without installing some sort of agent/client on one's computer." - the answer is YES.

Comment: @MichaelICE — No it isn't. You can't do P2P without installing an agent on the computer.

Comment: I stand corrected, I misread. Unfortunatly this question is one of the top answers for 'Can PHP be used to create P2P?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You could write a P2P client / server in PHP — but it would have to be installed on the participating computers.

You can't have PHP running on a webserver cause two other computers to communicate with each other without having P2P software installed.

You can't even use JavaScript to help — the same origin policy would prevent it.

JavaScript running a browser could use a PHP based server as a middleman so that two clients could communicate — but you aren't going to achieve P2P.

---

Since 2009 (when this answer was originally written), the WebRTC protocol was written and achieved [widespread support](https://caniuse.com/?search=WebRTC) among browsers.

This allows you to perform [peer-to-peer between web browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC/Peer-to-peer_communications_with_WebRTC) but you need to write the code in JavaScript (WebAssembly might also be an option and one that would let you write PHP.)

You also need a [bunch of non-peer server code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Protocols) to support WebRTC (e.g. for allow peer discovery and proxy data around firewalls) which you could write in PHP.

Comment: Why not try WebRTC? peer.js

Comment: This is not true, you CAN create a full P2P system in PHP using sockets. The original question didn't specify PHP running without a web server. I have created a true P2P framework for my own use and it is based on one in C++.

Comment: @MichaelICE — Umm. I said "You could write a P2P client / server in PHP — but it would have to be installed on the participating computers." and the question said "a php script that hosted on web server remote from both peers, so each peer have nothing but a browser."

Comment: @CMCDragonkai — Because it was released 2 years after I wrote this answer

Answer (score 2):

> without installing some sort of
>   agent/client on one's computer

Each computer would have to have the PHP binaries installed.

**EDIT**

I see in a different post you mentioned browser based.  Security restrictions in javascript would prohibit this type of interaction

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to implement a true peer-to-peer (P2P) network using only PHP, without relying on some other technology to establish peer connections.

PHP is a server-side scripting language that is used to generate dynamic web content. It is not designed to handle peer-to-peer communication directly, and lacks the necessary low-level network capabilities to establish and maintain direct connections between peers.

To implement a P2P network, you need a technology that allows peers to directly connect and exchange data without relying on a central server. This typically requires a low-level networking protocol like TCP or UDP, which can be accessed using programming languages like C++, Python, or Java.

However, it is possible to use PHP in conjunction with other technologies to implement a P2P network. For example, you could use PHP to implement a web-based interface for managing P2P connections and exchanging data, while relying on a lower-level networking protocol like WebRTC to establish direct connections between peers. This would require running a PHP script on a web server, but would allow peers to communicate directly without requiring any additional software installations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use php as script interpreter, php has implementation of sockets. No server would be needed in each script execution

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't peer-to-peer communication imply that communication is going directly from one client to another, without any servers in the middle?  Since PHP is a server-based software, I don't think any program you write on it can be considered true p2p.

However, if you want to enable client to client communications with a php server as the middle man, that's definitely possible.

Comment: Although, to run PHP scripts locally you would need to install a PHP interpreter, and if the OP doesn't want to install Flash or Java, I doubt they will want to install PHP locally

Answer (score -1):

In case someone comes here seeing if you can write P2P software in PHP, the answer is yes, in this case, Quentin's answer to the original question is correct, PHP would have to be installed on the computer.

You can do whatever you want to do in PHP, including writing true p2p software. To create a true P2P program in PHP, you would use PHP as an interpreted language WITHOUT a web server, and you would use sockets - just like you would in c/c++. The original accepted answer is right and wrong, unless however the original poster was asking if PHP running on a webserver could be a p2p client - which would of course be no.

Basically to do this, you'd basically write a php script that:

1. Opens a server socket connection (stream_socket_server/socket_create)
2. Find a list of peer IP's
3. Open a client connection to each peer
4. ...
5. Prove everyone wrong.

Comment: This won't work under the conditions of the question. You seem to have missed the last paragraph of the question.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, but its not what's generally called p2p, since there is a server in between. I have a feeling though that what you want to do is to have your peers communicate with each other, rather than have a direct connection between them with no 'middleman' server (which is what is normally meant by p2p)

Depending on the scalability requirements, implementing this kind of communication can be trivial (simple polling script on clients), or demanding (asynchronous comet server).

Answer (score -2):

both parties would need to be running a server such as apache although for demonstration purposes you could get away with just using the inbuilt php test server. Next you are going to have to research firewall hole punching in php  I saw a script i think on github but was long time ago . Yes it can be done , if your client is not a savvy programmer type you would probably need to  ensure that they have php installed and running. The path variable may not work unless you add it to the system registry in windows so make sure you provide a bat file that both would ensure the path is in the system registry so windows can find it .Sorry I am not a linux user.
Next  you have to develop the code. There are instrucions for how hole punching works and it does require a server on the public domain which is required to allow 2 computers to find each others ip address. Maybe you could rig up something on a free website such as [www.000.webhost.com](http://www.000.webhost.com) alternatively you could use some kind of a built in mechanism such as using the persons email address. To report the current ip.

The biggest problem is routers and firewalls but packets even if they are directed at a public ip still need to know the destination on a lan so the information on how to write the packet should be straight forwards. With any luck you might find a  script that has done most of the work for you.

Answer (score -3):

No, not really. PHP scripts are meant to run only for very small amount of time. Usually the default maximum runtime is two minutes which will be normally not enough for p2p communication. After this the script will be canceled though the server administrator can deactivate that. But even then the whole downloading time the http connection between the server and the client must be hold. The client's browser will show in this time its page loading indicator. If the connection breakes most web servers will kill the php script so the p2p download is canceled.

So it may be possible to implement the p2p protocol, but in a client/server scenario you run into problems with the execution model of php scripts.

Comment: The time execution of a php script can be unlimited if the scripts runs on php as interpreter